# In German, what does "Skalarraum" mean?

Tags: terminology, vector-fields, translation-request, mathematical-german

Is it just that $\mathbb K$ is the *Skalarraum* of $\mathbb K^{m \times n}$, or does it have other applications also?

From a [Google search](https://www.google.at/search?q=skalarraum&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ixo4VtTgAYOAU831uLgO#q=%22skalarraum%22) it would seem so, but I'd like to make sure, as none of the pages gives a definition/explanation.

And what would be a more commonly used synonym?

Comment: The German *Raum* is the equivalent of the English *room*.

Comment: @Lucian, most probably it's *space* in this context.

Comment: @lhf: They are [cognates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s the *scalar field* of whatever vector space is under discussion.

Comment: I saw that on Wikipedia, but that seems to correspond to the German "Skalarfeld", which in turn seems to differ from "Skalarraum", unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: @Maasumi: You can’t expect necessarily to be able to translate by cognates. *Skalarfeld* is scalar field in the physical sense, e.g., the function that assigns to each point of some volume the temperature at that point. *Field* in the algebraic sense is *Körper*, and I’ve seen *Skalarkörper* and *Grundkörper* for the field of scalars of a vector space. I’ve seen *Skalarraum* only a few times, but in every case it’s referred to the field of scalars of some vector space – usually an infinite-dimensional space, though I don’t know whether that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "field of scalars", in the context of vector spaces.